# prefixing !!! with the package name, rlang

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

Is it possible to use the `!!!` like so:

```r
dplyr::count(df, rlang::`!!!`(rlang::syms(variables)))
```

instead of:

```r
dplyr::count(df, !!!syms(variables))
```

EDITED:

It is not possible.

So now the question becomes what is the alternative to using `!!!`?

Comment: What happened when you  tried it with data?

Comment: Indeed, I just tried. it cannot

Comment: There's your answer!

Comment: The `!!!` notation isn't the name of a function, it's just the regular operator `!` used three times.  Only in tidyverse non-standard evaluation will it be interpreted the way you want.

Comment: Yeah, it is not an actual operator, it is interpreted. Why do you need an alternative? Why not just use it? Even if you are making your own package, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What's `variables`, a string vector? Is this inside a function?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan:  Try typing `rlang::"!!!"` in the console (or use backticks instead of quotes).  It's a function, but that's not the function that gets called when you use `!!!` in an expression.

Comment: There is no need for prefixing `!!!` or `!!` or `{{` with `rlang::`. These operators are not function calls, they are specially interpreted by rlang in data-masked arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `rlang`, we may use `all_of` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   count(across(all_of(variables)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are soft-deprecated functions in `rlang` called `UQ()` and `UQS()` (unquote and unquote-splice). But they should not be used with `rlang::` in front either.

**In short, just use `!!!`.**

But here is an example of what you are asking about.

```r
df <- mtcars
variables <- c("cyl", "gear")

dplyr::count(df, rlang::UQS(syms(variables)))
```

If you do this, it will yell at you.

```r
Warning message:
Prefixing `UQS()` with the rlang namespace is deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use the non-prefixed form or `!!!` instead.

  # Bad:
  rlang::expr(mean(rlang::UQS(args)))

  # Ok:
  rlang::expr(mean(UQS(args)))

  # Good:
  rlang::expr(mean(!!!args))
```

---

Here is an extract from `help("nse-force")`.

> Calling UQ() and UQS() with the rlang namespace qualifier is deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0. Just use the unqualified forms instead:
>
> ```
> # Bad
> rlang::expr(mean(rlang::UQ(var) * 100))
>
> # Ok
> rlang::expr(mean(UQ(var) * 100))
>
> # Good
> rlang::expr(mean(!!var * 100))
> ```
>
> Supporting namespace qualifiers complicates the implementation of unquotation and is misleading as to the nature of unquoting operators (which are syntactic operators that operate at quotation-time rather than function calls at evaluation-time).
>
> UQ() and UQS() were soft-deprecated in rlang 0.2.0 in order to make the syntax of quasiquotation more consistent. The prefix forms are now `!!`() and `!!!`() which is consistent with other R operators (e.g. `+`(a, b) is the prefix form of a + b).
>
> Note that the prefix forms are not as relevant as before because !! now has the right operator precedence, i.e. the same as unary - or +. It is thus safe to mingle it with other operators, e.g. !!a + !!b does the right thing. In addition the parser now strips one level of parentheses around unquoted expressions. This way (!!"foo")(...) expands to foo(...). These changes make the prefix forms less useful.
>
> Finally, the named functional forms UQ() and UQS() were misleading because they suggested that existing knowledge about functions is applicable to quasiquotation. This was reinforced by the visible definitions of these functions exported by rlang and by the tidy eval parser interpreting rlang::UQ() as !!. In reality unquoting is not a function call, it is a syntactic operation. The operator form makes it clearer that unquoting is special.